# Predicate Logic, Proof of validity . How to remove negation infront of existential quantifier?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, proof-theory, natural-deduction

$\forall x~(P(x) \to (Q(x) \lor R(x))), \lnot \exists x~(P(x) \land R(x)) \vdash \forall x~(P(x) \to Q(x))$

I am stuck on how to get rid of the negation on "$\lnot \exists x~(P(x) \land R(x))$" in this particular case. I have a relative idea of going about this sentence , where first using 2nd premise eliminating the "$\exists x$" and then getting the "$P(x_0)$" and "$R(x_0)$" respectively, then after that using "$\forall x$" elimination to get "$P(x_0) \to (Q(x_0) \lor R(x_0))$", that then allows me to use the $P(x_0)$ from previous "$P(x_0) \land R(x_0)$" to eliminate the conditional connective that allows me to have two sub-proofs to eliminate the disjunction. I can then do conditional introduction giving "$P(x_0) \to Q(x_0)$" needed and after that just introduction of $\forall x$ that gives me $\forall x~(P(x) \to Q(x))$ what I am looking for.

My problem is on how to get rid of the negation in 2nd premise in this sentence or am I going in the wrong direction on this one?
Any advice would help.
Thanks!

My attempt thus far:
[image: First part]

[image: Second Part]

Comment: You could always do $\neg\exists x(P(x)\land R(x)) \;\to\;\forall x \neg(P(x)\land R(x)).$

Comment: How would I go about that ,since I need to get to ∀x (P(x) → Q(x)) at the end and can't change the premises?

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I've changed the title.

Comment: If you're in the Natural Deduction rules, you need to use $\forall$ Intro.

Comment: I had ∀x intro at end of the sentence to give ∀x (P(x) → Q(x)). Is this what you are referring to?

Comment: Could you prove this statement informally if you had to ?  Like could you explain in plain English why (if?) the statement is true?

Comment: @DanielV No, It has to be proof of validity by natural deduction of predicate logic.

Comment: @KazyKamakaze I mean to ask what is your ability, not what is the assignment, because it reads as if you don't even have an informal proof in mind.  It might help if you add to your question how you would prove the theorem in plain english.

Comment: @DanielV The question literally says on quote "Using the rules of natural deduction, prove the validity of the following sequents in predicate logic. In all cases, number your steps, indicate which rule you are using and indicate subproofs clearly."  like I explained before.

Comment: Line 7 should have the same scope as the premises.  Lines 23 through 28 currently aren't necessary.   After you have ($\lnot$P(x0)$\lor$$\lnot$R(x0)), look at the conclusion.  So, assume P(x0).  Then look at the first premise, and soon after use modus ponens.  Also, take P(x0) and  ($\lnot$P(x0)$\lor$$\lnot$R(x0)) and derive $\lnot$R(x0).  Similarly, derive Q(x0).  Then discharge the assumption, and generalize.

Comment: @DougSpoonwood Can you perhaps show me how it's done , i'm completely lost now with this.

Comment: @DougSpoonwood Can you please use my example and show where i've done wrong and how to finish it. I'm at a point of giving up on this question.

Comment: @KazyKamakaze I don't know *all* of the permissible rules of inference for your system (they often vary).  So, no, I can't finish the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am stuck on how to get rid of the negation on "$\lnot \exists x~(P(x) \land R(x))$" in this particular case. I have a relative idea of going about this sentence , where first using 2nd premise eliminating the "$\exists x$" and then getting the "$P(x_0)$" and "$R(x_0)$" respectively, then after that using "$\forall x$" elimination to get "$P(x_0) \to (Q(x_0) \lor R(x_0))$", that then allows me to use the $P(x_0)$ from previous "$P(x_0) \land R(x_0)$" to eliminate the conditional connective that allows me to have 2 sub proofs to eliminate the disjunction. I can then do conditional introduction giving "$P(x_0) \to Q(x_0)$" needed and after that just introduction of $\forall x$ that gives me $\forall x~(P(x) \to Q(x))$ what I am looking for.

You have the right idea. However, you should *start* with assuming $P(x_0)$ for an otherwise arbitrary $x_0$, then eliminate the universal quantifier in the **first** premise to that witness, eliminate the conditional, and *thence* eliminate the resulting disjunction. (Since you have $P(x_0)$ and $Q(x_0)\lor R(x_0)$ at that point.)

In the left case, $Q(x_0)$ is trivially derived, while in the right case is where the magic happens.  From $R(x_0)$ and the assumed $P(x_0)$ derive the existance of $P(x_0)\land R(x_0)$, that is $\exists x~(P(x)\land R(x)$, which would contradict the second premise. Explode that contradiction.

Then introduce a universal quantifier, deducing $\forall x~(P(x)\to Q(x))$ as desired.

$\def\fitch#1#2{\quad\begin{array}{|l} #1\\\hline #2\end{array}}\fitch{~~1.~~\forall x~(P(x)\to(Q(x)\lor R(x))\hspace{10ex}\textsf{Premise}\\~~2.~~\neg\exists x~(P(x)\land R(x))\hspace{18ex}\textsf{Premise}}{\fitch{~~3.~~[x_0]\hspace{10ex}\textsf{Arbitrary Witness}}{\fitch{~~4.~~P(x_0)\hspace{10ex}\textsf{Assumption}}{~~5.~~P(x_0)\to(Q(x_0)\lor R(x_0))\hspace{10ex}\textsf{Universal Elimination}\\~~6.~~Q(x_0)\lor R(x_0)\hspace{10ex}\textsf{Conditional Elimination}\\\fitch{~~7.~~Q(x_0)\hspace{10ex}\textsf{Assumption (Left Case)}}{}\\~~8.~~Q(x_0)\to Q(x_0)\hspace{10ex}\textsf{Conditional Introduction}\\\fitch{~~9.~~R(x_0)\hspace{10ex}\textsf{Assumption (Right Case)}}{10.~~P(x_0)\land R(x_0)\hspace{10ex}\textsf{Conjunction Introduction}\\11.~~\exists x~(P(x)\land R(x))\ldots\hspace{10ex}\textsf{Existential Introduction}\\12.~~\bot\hspace{10ex}\textsf{Negation Elimination}\\13.~~Q(x_0)\hspace{10ex}\textsf{Explosion (Ex Falsum Quodlibet)}}\\14.~~R(x_0)\to Q(x_0)\hspace{10ex}\textsf{Conditional Introduction}\\15.~~Q(x_0)\hspace{10ex}\textsf{Disjunction Elimination}}\\16.~~P(x_0)\to Q(x_0)\hspace{10ex}\textsf{Conditional Introduction}}\\17.~~\forall x~(P(x)\to Q(x))\hspace{10ex}\textsf{Universal Introduction}}$

Comment: What you mean by magic? So from what you indicating here you don't even need the second premise to reach the conclusion?  Otherwise did I understand it wrong?

Comment: You do need to use the second premise, and you said that you knew what to do with it.  Work your magic there.

Comment: Yeah that's in the context of how I went about the sentence , but the way you went about it has confused me a bit where you actually left out the part that I was struggling with which is ¬∃x (P(x)∧R(x)) which is the negation part.

Comment: Would also like to find out how you displayed the Fitch style lines in Stack exchange as to in the future be able to explain a question better?

Comment: My whole problem from the start is I did not know how to eliminate/deal with the ¬∃x (P(x)∧R(x)) Premise as the negation is throwing me off.

Comment: You have $P(X_0)$ and $R(X_0)$ assumed, and $\neg\exists x~(P(x)\land R(x))$ as a premise. ... The negation is the problem, so try to eliminate it.  If only you had a witness to what the premise claimed did not exist...

Comment: I can't follow your example exactly as I don't get what you did in some of your steps as you have no rule indicators next to the steps. The whole reason I came to ask a question is not only to solve the problem but to learn how to solve the problem, so as in the future I can solve questions in same structure in a clear and concise way.

Comment: For example "Q(x0)→Q(x0)" What do you mean here? Is it conditional introduction? Perhaps is something else? As there is no rule indicator next to the answer I don't know what you did there and same is with ". . . " in the middle. I know this is tedious but do have patience, everyone had to learn somewhere  :D

Comment: What is a witness? I've not seen this term used as of yet in first order logic. Can you please clarify your answer? Thank you!

Comment: A witness is a *term* introduced for the purpose of quantifier elimination and introduction rules.  Here, $x_0$ is an arbitrary witness so we may use Universal Elimination: substituting the arbitrary witness for the bound variable.

Comment: At line 11 did you do existential introduction on P(x0)∧R(x0) to get the contradiction? Had to look up what explosion was on line 13, never worked with it before. Learning something new here everyday. Want to know h is line 14 conjunction introduction? Is it not conditional introduction? Want to also ask why did you do conditional introduction on line 8?

Comment: Thank you for the edits! Would like to find out why you did conditional introduction at lines 8 and 14?

Answer (score 2):

Basic idea: Assume P(a).  Deduce Q(a) within the scope of P(a).

For a hint on getting rid of the negation note that existential introduction doesn't have any restrictions, does it?

More detail:

Assume (P(a)$\land$R(a)), where 'a' is a constant.  Then you can get a contradiction (hint: use existential introduction).  So, you can infer $\lnot$(P(a)$\land$R(a)).  But, then 'a' will appear and not appear anywhere else in assumptions made.  Thus, you'll have the ability to use universal introduction, to have ∀x$\lnot$(P(x)$\land$R(x)).  Then using a De Morgan law you have ∀x($\lnot$P(x)$\lor$$\lnot$R(x)).

Then assume P(a).  By universal elimination you can infer ($\lnot$P(a)$\lor$$\lnot$R(a)).  So, you can manage to get to $\lnot$R(a).  Also, derive (Q(a)$\lor$R(a)) by using the first premise and P(a).  So, you can then derive Q(a).

Then discharge P(a) yielding (P(a)$\rightarrow$Q(a)).  And note that 'a' doesn't appear in any assumptions still in effect for the last step.

Comment: Is there a way you can show how this works as I am new to predicate logic and have not yet come across a negation in front of a quantifier?

Comment: Since I am learning to questions not only with specified natural deduction rules but also how it's implemented in the box model as well.

Comment: What caught me off guard is how to implement this in a box model using natural deduction rules , since I have a relative idea of how to go answering the question the problem is at implementing it in the box model as to indicate each step followed.

Comment: @KazyKamakaze Every time I say 'assume' introduce the start of a new box.  At the spot which corresponds to the end of the first paragraph, close the first box.  Also, when I say discharge, a box should get closed.  In general, a new box starts with an assumption and ends with a conclusion.

Comment: Now the problem I have is i have never done De Morgans law with predicate logic only with propositional logic and have only been using variables (ex x0) and not constants in predicate logic with ruling out quantifiers, this is why I am getting somewhat confused as you are stating something I haven't done as of yet. As you can see i'm still a bit new to all of this and want to learn and I know it's a bit frustrating to help someone not yet on the same wavelength as you in what you are trying to explain.

Comment: Are there maybe any examples I can look at, so as to at least learn how to do what you've explained?

Comment: I've followed you till de Morgan's  law implementation. Where  ∀x¬(P(x) ∧ R(x)) is an introduction of ∀x , can you perhaps show me how you did the rest?

Comment: @KazyKamakaze P(x) and R(x) have the forms of propositions in predicate logic.  So, if you proved $\lnot$(A$\land$B) is equivalent to ($\lnot$A$\lor$$\lnot$B) in propositional logic, then you just substitute each A with P(x) and each B with R(x).  Also, I think, though I'm not entirely sure, you can use 'x$_0$' instead of a constant like 'a'.

Comment: i have done till ¬ P(x0) ∨ ¬ R(x0) and then did disjunction elimination which then gives ¬ P(x0) as you've said thus far. But now what I would like to know is what do you do with this  ¬ P(x0) since what you require is just P(x) to derive Q(x)∨R(x) and then derive Q(X) so you can do conditional introduction and then universal introduction. So what is the reason for getting ¬ P(x0). This I do not understand. BTW "x0" is just a variable instead of using a constant.

Comment: @KazyKamakaze I didn't say anything about getting ¬ P(x0), nor anything about $\lnot$P(a).

Comment: "By universal elimination you can infer (¬P(a)∨¬R(a)). So, you can manage to get to ¬R(a)"  ¬R(a) through disjunction elimination? Sorry meant to put ¬ R(x0) ,copied and pasted wrong ,apologies. So what do you do with ¬R(x0) once you have derived it from ¬ P(x0) ∨ ¬ R(x0)?
 I understand the part after this where you assume P(x0) and derive Q(x0)∨R(x0). and thru disjunction elimination get Q(x0) and do conditional introduction and then universal introduction as the last step.

Comment: @KazyKamakaze "¬R(a) through disjunction elimination?"  Yes, that's correct.  "So what do you do with ¬R(x0) once you have derived it from ¬ P(x0) ∨ ¬ R(x0)?"  See the paragraph that begins with "Assume P(a)."  If you have more questions, maybe it works out better to edit your post and put up what you have so far.

Comment: I've added 2 images of what i've got thus far, but I feel there must be a shorter way of doing it ,since I'm already 28 lines into the proof and it's not done yet.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to eliminate the negation in front of the existential, use that statement as part of a proof bu contradiction.

To be a bit more specific: ypu need to show that every P is a Q. OK, so take any arbitrary object that is a P. Now assume (here the proof by contradiciotn starts) that it is not a Q. Well, by premise 1, we know the object is either a Q or an R ... but we just assumed that it was not a Q, so it must be an R. But then the object is both a P and a R, so there is something that is a p and a R (you'll probably do an existential Introduction at this point) and so that contrdicts premise 2. So, the assumption must be withdrawn, and so the object is a Q. Finally, since the object was arbitrary, we can say that any Q is an R.

Now, I don't know the specific rules of your proof system, but chances are it can implement this proof idea. Good luck!

Comment: The rule system is rules of natural deduction for predicate logic. Proof of validity of sequant.

Comment: @KazyKamakaze there are many different systems of natural deduction, so I'll leave it up to you to translate my informal proof into a formal one. Anyway, the idea is to *not* infer anything from the negation of the existential, and instead simply use it in a proof by contradiction as I indicated.... whatever the detailed rules are, that will probably save you a lot of steps and headaches.